# $_SESSION Variable not available after setting

Tags: php

Click on a button executes this Ajax request

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "json-responses.php?fct=validationCode&userMail=" + userMail,
        success: sendValidationCode()       
    });
```

if successfull the sendValidationCode() function is invoked which executes another Ajax request

```
function sendValidationCode()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "json-responses.php?fct=sendValidationCode&userMail=" + userMail,
            success: function()
            {
                location.replace("reset-forgotten-pw?user=" + userMail);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the code from the json-responses.php file :

```
if ($_GET['fct'] == 'validationCode')
{
    $_SESSION['v_Code'] = random_str(6, '0123456789');

    $result = createValidationCode($connectionObject, $_GET['userMail'], do_crypt($_SESSION['v_Code']));
    echo $result;
}

if ($_GET['fct']  == 'sendValidationCode')
    {
        $volTo = $_GET['userMail'];
        $volAckString = $image . "<h1>Password assistance</h1><p>To verify your identity, please use the following code:</p>".$_SESSION['v_Code'].;

        unset($_SESSION['v_Code']);
    }
```

I was assuming that as the 'validationCode' part is called before the $_SESSION['V_Code'] variable would be set and available when the second file invokes 'sendValidationCode' file. However the mail the user receives does not contain any validation code. Now if I restart the process (means the session remains open during the 'validationCode' part I get a new $_SESSION variable and in the 'sendValidationCode' part the "old" $_SESSION['v_Code'] is sent to the user. (Besides the unset.... does not have any effect.)

Comment: Dont forget `session_start();` ... I'm not seeing it in your code presented.

Comment: It is included in the header (I did not print it here)